# Protected Non-Static Variable in Java Interface

Tags: java, interface

I know that variables in Java Interface are implicitly `public`, `static`, and `final`. I understand why it is the way it is. But I have a requirement where there are two abstract classes that implement the same interface. There's a `protected non-static final Map` in both of these classes and they serve the same purpose.

I was wondering if there's a way where instead of having two different Maps, I could move it to the interface and write a default method that serves the purpose. Moving the Map to the interface will make it public and static, I want the map to retain being protected and non-static.

Is there any other way through which I can achieve what I'm trying to do? Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot specify a field in an interface that a class must provide.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, I just want to know if there's any way to achieve what I'm trying to.

Comment: You can declare a method in your interface and have your classes uses a map field in their implementations.

Comment: That's exactly what's happening right now, it's just without a method in the interface. There're two different Maps and two different implementations serving the same purpose.

Comment: You can move the map to an abstract superclass that both classes extend